# Lambda with two dataframe columns as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda function to update a new column in a dataframe. The lambda function will be taking two other existing columns as arguments. I am getting an error when trying this. The error states that one argument is missing, but I believe I am passing the Y argument.

```
def rule_greater_than(col, weight_col, weight, threshold):
    if col >= threshold:
        weight_col = weight
        else:
        weight_col = 0
    return weight_col  

def resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule(df, weight, threshold):
    df['resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule'] = None
    df['resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule'] = df[['resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity',
                                                   'resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule']].apply(lambda x, y: rule_greater_than(x, y, weight,
                                                                                                                               threshold))
    return df

resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule(x, 0.5, 0.03)
x


TypeError: ("<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'", 'occurred at index resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity')
```

Comment: You're not. You're passing a function, which returns a single value

Comment: You're also going about this incorrectly. You don't want to use `apply` here, there's a vectorized approach

Comment: @roganjosh: what vectorized approach do you recommend ?

Comment: `df['resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity_rule'] = np.where(df['resumeJobDescriptionSimilarity'] >= threshold, weight, 0)`